# The max norm $|. |_{\infty}$ is generating a metrics

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> I want to prove that the max norm $\|\cdot \|_{\infty}$ generates in the
>   space of continuos functions $C([a,b])$ a metrics.

Well, I am not sure how to properly make it. I just know that if I have two functions $f$ and $g$ then for all $x \in [a,b]$ a I can find the distance between those two functions such that $\|f - g\|$. For the $x \in [a,b]$ I can find out the biggest possible distance between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ by $max_{x \in [a,b]}|f(x) - g(x)|$. Is this the metrics or do I have to do more or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are, I think, trying to say:

The norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ generates a metric on $C([a,b])$ by $$d(f,g) = \|f-g\| = \max_{x \in [a,b]} \{| f(x) -g(x) |\}$$

This is true, as *any* norm $\|\cdot\|$ on a linear space defines a metric in this way (norm of the difference).
We use $\|-f\| = \|f\|$ for symmetry, $\|f\| = 0 \implies f=0$ for the non-pseudometricity, and $\|f+g\| \le \|f\| + \|g\|$ for the triangle inequality of that metric.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I meant, I just didn't formulate it well. So is it enough?

Comment: @Leif you still either have to show the fact that it's a norm, or the fact that norms induce metrics, or both, maybe.

Comment: Ok, it's ok. I just wanted to know If I see it the right way because this topic is new for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that it satisfies the four conditions of a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)):

1. $d(f,g)\ge 0$,
2. $d(f,g)=0 \Leftrightarrow f=g $,
3. $d(f,g)=d(g,f)$,
4. $d(f,g) \le d(f,h) + d(h,g) $,

where, as you mentioned above, $d(f,g)=\max_{[a,b]} |f(x)-g(x)|$.